# Make the image scrollable

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, tabpage

I have TabPageControl and some TabPages inside it. I need to put the big image into the tabpage and change it every 30 sec and I want to see just a part of the image. So I need scrolling. But I have the next trouble: when i slide the scroll bars the image vanishes or smears in 1 black stripe. I've googled this trouble but found no information.

Comment: Is it correct to assume you are using WinForms? Are you putting the picture in a PictureBox control?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? Do you use a PictureBox to show your image? Show us some part of your code please...

Comment: I use WinForms and I don't put the picture in a picturebox. i get the graphics from the tabpage.backgroundimage and draw over it. `grBackground = Graphics.FromImage(this.currTPage.BackgroundImage);
grBackground.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    grBackground.DrawLine(drawingPen, point1, point2);`

Comment: Vasilii can you show us some code, in which event do you paint and how you do it?

Comment: you can edit your question and add the code don't use comment for that

Comment: Two things you have to do: call Invalidate() in the Scroll event handler and e.Graphics.Transform() in the Paint event handler.  You'll however get flicker, TabPage is not double-buffered by default.  Using a PictureBox is the better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a PictureBox for this.

Set the TabPage.AutoScroll property to true, this will cause the tab page to show scrollbars if the content is larger than the tab page.

Set the PictureBox.SizeMode to PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize, this will make the Picture box control size it self to the size of the loaded image. If the picture box is larger than the tab page it is on, the tab page will show the necessary scrollbars and they should work as expected.

```
  tabPage1.AutoScroll = true;
  pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

You can then draw on the picture box, if required. You would normally do this drawing in the `Paint` event of the picture box.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to put the picturebox inside a FlolayoutPanel. Set the Auto scroll of the FlolayoutPanel to true and set the picture size mode to normal